# Returning TOP n rows from a GROUP By query with INNER Joins From multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tried several solutions found on your site and nothing quite matches up with what I need. In SQL Server I need to make a multiple table join using `GROUP BY` query and return only the `TOP 1` row from each group. Here is the base code that returns the desired records, but will return all records matching the criteria:

```
SELECT MIN(Maintenance_Log.Log_StartDate) As MaintDate
     , Manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name
     , GL_Inventory.Inventory_Model
     , GL_Inventory.Inventory_SerialNr
     , Maintenance_Log.Event_ID
     , Maintenance_Log.Inventory_ID 
FROM Maintenance_Log 
INNER JOIN GL_Inventory ON Maintenance_Log.Inventory_ID = GL_Inventory.Inventory_ID 
INNER JOIN Manufacturer ON GL_Inventory.Manufacturer_ID = Manufacturer.Manufacturer_ID  
WHERE Maintenance_Log.Owner_ID = @OwnerID 
  AND Maintenance_Log.Log_CompletedDate Is Null 
GROUP BY Maintenance_Log.Inventory_ID
       , Maintenance_Log.Log_StartDate
       , Manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name
       , GL_Inventory.Inventory_Model
       , GL_Inventory.Inventory_SerialNr
       , Maintenance_Log.Event_ID
```

The results returned are:

```
2016-06-30 09:00:00.000 GLOCK   G19 Gen 4   ABDE1234    2   6
2016-07-28 09:00:00.000 GLOCK   G19 Gen 4   ABDE1234    3   6
2016-08-25 09:00:00.000 GLOCK   G19 Gen 4   ABDE1234    4   6
2016-09-29 09:00:00.000 GLOCK   G19 Gen 4   ABDE1234    5   6
2016-10-27 09:00:00.000 GLOCK   G19 Gen 4   ABDE1234    6   6
2016-11-24 09:00:00.000 GLOCK   G19 Gen 4   ABDE1234    7   6
2016-12-29 09:00:00.000 GLOCK   G19 Gen 4   ABDE1234    8   6
2016-07-01 09:00:00.000 S&W     642         WQ32De45    9   7
2016-08-05 09:00:00.000 S&W     642         WQ32De45    10  7
2016-09-02 09:00:00.000 S&W     642         WQ32De45    11  7
2016-10-07 09:00:00.000 S&W     642         WQ32De45    12  7
2016-11-04 09:00:00.000 S&W     642         WQ32De45    13  7
2016-12-02 09:00:00.000 S&W     642         WQ32De45    14  7
```

I want to return only the **TOP 1** row from each group based on the last digit in the row which is the `Inventory_ID` number, not all rows that match the criteria.

Comment: The last last digit repeats

Answer (score 0):

This is your query, formatted and simplified using table aliases:

```
SELECT MIN(l.Log_StartDate) As MaintDate, m.Manufacturer_Name, 
       i.Inventory_Model, i.Inventory_SerialNr, l.Event_ID, l.Inventory_ID 
FROM Maintenance_Log l INNER JOIN
     GL_Inventory i
     ON l.Inventory_ID = i.Inventory_ID INNER JOIN
     Manufacturer m
     ON i.Manufacturer_ID = m.Manufacturer_ID)
WHERE l.Owner_ID = @OwnerID AND l.Log_CompletedDate Is Null 
GROUP BY l.Log_StartDate, m.Manufacturer_Name, i.Inventory_Model, 
         i.Inventory_SerialNr, l.Event_ID, l.Inventory_ID ;
```

First, I note that `Log_StartDate` is both in the `GROUP BY` and an argument to `MIN()`.  So, I wonder if this would fix your problem:

```
SELECT MIN(l.Log_StartDate) As MaintDate, m.Manufacturer_Name, 
       i.Inventory_Model, i.Inventory_SerialNr, l.Event_ID, l.Inventory_ID 
FROM Maintenance_Log l INNER JOIN
     GL_Inventory i
     ON l.Inventory_ID = i.Inventory_ID INNER JOIN
     Manufacturer m
     ON i.Manufacturer_ID = m.Manufacturer_ID)
WHERE l.Owner_ID = @OwnerID AND l.Log_CompletedDate Is Null 
GROUP BY m.Manufacturer_Name, i.Inventory_Model, 
         i.Inventory_SerialNr, l.Event_ID, l.Inventory_ID ;
```

If you still want one row for the largest inventory_id, then you can use window functions:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT MIN(l.Log_StartDate) As MaintDate, m.Manufacturer_Name, 
             i.Inventory_Model, i.Inventory_SerialNr, l.Event_ID, l.Inventory_ID ,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.Manufacturer_Name,  i.Inventory_Model, i.Inventory_SerialNr, l.Event_ID
                                ORDER BY l.Inventory_ID  -- Do you want this ASC or DESC ?
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM Maintenance_Log l INNER JOIN
           GL_Inventory i
           ON l.Inventory_ID = i.Inventory_ID INNER JOIN
           Manufacturer m
           ON i.Manufacturer_ID = m.Manufacturer_ID)
      WHERE l.Owner_ID = @OwnerID AND l.Log_CompletedDate Is Null 
      GROUP BY m.Manufacturer_Name, i.Inventory_Model, 
               i.Inventory_SerialNr, l.Event_ID, l.Inventory_ID
     )
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the feedback. However, It doesn't provide a solution to returning only the top 1 record in each Group. I have rewritten the code to hopefully show more of what I am looking for help with. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT ML.Log_StartDate As MaintDate
     , M.M_Name
     , I.Inventory_Model
     , I.Inventory_SerialNr
     , ML.Event_ID
     , ML.Inventory_ID 
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ML.Inventory_ID 
                                    ORDER BY ML.Log_StartDate DESC)rn
FROM Maintenance_Log ML 
INNER JOIN GL_Inventory I ON ML.Inventory_ID = I.Inventory_ID 
INNER JOIN Manufacturer M ON I.M_ID = M.M_ID  
WHERE ML.Owner_ID = @OwnerID 
  AND ML.Log_CompletedDate Is Null 
)
SELECT MaintDate
      ,M_Name
      ,Inventory_Model
      ,Inventory_SerialNr
      ,Event_ID
      ,Inventory_ID
FROM X
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks M.Ali, with a few modifications this works perfectly. I really appreciated the help. Just so you know I changed the ORDER BY to ML.Log_Start ASC in order to get the earliest on top and had to change the  "INNER JOIN Manufacturer M ON I.M_ID = M.M_ID" to "INNER JOIN Manufacturer M ON I.Manufacturer_ID = M.Manufacturer_ID". Once I did that it works just like I wanted. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in this situation (need the top 1 result from a subquery for each row being joined), CROSS APPLY is what you want.

Whereas INNER JOIN (select top 1 ...) will use the same "top 1" row for each row being joined, CROSS APPLY (select top 1...) will evaluate the expression for each row being joined.

If you need it to behave as a LEFT OUTER JOIN would (not filtering rows with no result in the expression), use OUTER APPLY instead.

Answer (score 0):

The query did what you asked for because of the uniqueness of each line.

Based on the data you posted (with the assumption is the first date will have the smallest Maintenance_Log.Event_ID), the query below might be a solution.

```
 SELECT MIN(Maintenance_Log.Log_StartDate) As MaintDate
     , Manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name
     , GL_Inventory.Inventory_Model
     , GL_Inventory.Inventory_SerialNr
     , MIN(Maintenance_Log.Event_ID)
     , Maintenance_Log.Inventory_ID 
FROM Maintenance_Log 
INNER JOIN GL_Inventory ON Maintenance_Log.Inventory_ID = GL_Inventory.Inventory_ID 
INNER JOIN Manufacturer ON GL_Inventory.Manufacturer_ID = Manufacturer.Manufacturer_ID  
WHERE Maintenance_Log.Owner_ID = @OwnerID 
  AND Maintenance_Log.Log_CompletedDate Is Null 
GROUP BY Maintenance_Log.Inventory_ID
       , Maintenance_Log.Log_StartDate
       , Manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name
       , GL_Inventory.Inventory_Model
       , GL_Inventory.Inventory_SerialNr
       --, Maintenance_Log.Event_ID
```